# How to override default caching of node_modules while building Node.js application in Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Is it possible to override the default behavior of Bluemix to cache the node_modules installed by NPM during builds ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior in Bluemix is to cache all node_modules installed by NPM.
However, we can use the NODE_MODULES_CACHE variable to determine whether or not the Node buildpack uses or ignores the cache from previous builds.

To disable caching set NODE_MODULES_CACHE to false by executing the below CF command.

$ cf set-env myapp NODE_MODULES_CACHE false

Answer (score 4):

Bluemix maintains a cache directory per node application, that is persisted between builds. The cache stores resolved dependencies so they are not downloaded and installed every time the app is deployed. Use the NODE_MODULES_CACHE variable to determine whether or not the Node buildpack uses or ignores the cache from previous builds. The default value is true.

```
    $ cf set-env myapp NODE_MODULES_CACHE false
```

Note that node_modules that are included in your application are **not** cached.

You can use a *cacheDirectories* array in your top-level *package.json* to achieve fine grained control over what modules are cached. When the *cacheDirectories* element is present in the *package.json* only those modules which are in the *cacheDirectories* array will be cached. In the following example only *node_modules* and *bower_components* are cached:

```
{
  "cacheDirectories": ["node_modules","bower_components"],
  ...
}
```

More information [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/runtimes/nodejs/index.html#nodejs_runtime).